# Running script at startup with python

Tags: python, operating-system, startup

I'm trying to create a python script that automatically runs at startup but since I need it to work on all platforms it cannot be run with something like Task scheduler on Windows. Is it possible to do that with python ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a batch script that runs at startup. This batch script would `cd` to the directory containing the python file that you want to run, and ultimately run the python file by doing `python main.py`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that ?

Comment: you can place the .bat file in the Startup folder in windows

Comment: I'm going to try and do that but since I don't know batch are there any alternatives ?